# Не могу вычислить размер unmanaged через Marshal.SizeOf структуры в C#

Tags: c#, c, dll, marshal

Есть некоторая структура переделанная из C в C#, так как библиотека (DLL) написана на C, но необходимо ее использовать в проекте на C#.

Вот код структуры на C#:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
#pragma warning disable IDE1006 // Naming Styles
public struct rtksvr_t
#pragma warning restore IDE1006 // Naming Styles
{
/* RTK server type */
   public int state;          /* server state (0:stop,1:running) */
   public int cycle;          /* processing cycle (ms) */
   public int nmeacycle;      /* NMEA request cycle (ms) (0:no req) */
   public int nmeareq;        /* NMEA request (0:no,1:nmeapos,2:single sol) */
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3)]
   public double[] nmeapos;  /* NMEA request position (ecef) (m) */
   public int buffsize;       /* input buffer size (bytes) */
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3)]
   public int[] format;      /* input format {rov,base,corr} */
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 2)]
   public solopt_t[] solopt; /* output solution options {sol1,sol2} */
   public int navsel;         /* ephemeris select (0:all,1:rover,2:base,3:corr) */
   public int nsbs;           /* number of sbas message */
   public int nsol;           /* number of solution buffer */
   public rtk_t rtk;          /* RTK control/result struct */
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3)]
   public int[] nb;         /* bytes in input buffers {rov,base} */
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 2)]
   public int[] nsb;         /* bytes in soulution buffers */
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3)]
   public int[] npb;         /* bytes in input peek buffers */
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3)]
   public byte[] buff; /* input buffers {rov,base,corr} */
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 2)]
   public byte[] sbuf; /* output buffers {sol1,sol2} */
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3)]
   public byte[] pbuf; /* peek buffers {rov,base,corr} */
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = MAXSOLBUF)]
   public sol_t[] solbuf; /* solution buffer */
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3 * 10)]
   public int[] nmsg; /* input message counts */
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3)]
   public raw_t[] raw;     /* receiver raw control {rov,base,corr} */
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3)]
   public rtcm_t[] rtcm;     /* RTCM control {rov,base,corr} */
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3)]
   public gtime_t[] ftime;   /* download time {rov,base,corr} */
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3 * MAXSTRPATH)]
   public char[] files; /* download paths {rov,base,corr} */
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3 * MAXOBSBUF)]
   public obs_t obs; /* observation data {rov,base,corr} */
   public nav_t nav;          /* navigation data */
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = MAXSBSMSG)]
   public sbsmsg_t sbsmsg; /* SBAS message buffer */
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 8)]
   public stream_t stream; /* streams {rov,base,corr,sol1,sol2,logr,logb,logc} */
   public IntPtr moni;     /* monitor stream */
   public uint tick;  /* start tick */
   public IntPtr thread;    /* server thread */
   public int cputime;        /* CPU time (ms) for a processing cycle */
   public int prcout;         /* missing observation data count */
   public int nave;           /* number of averaging base pos */
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3)]
   public double[] rb_ave;   /* averaging base pos */
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3 * MAXRCVCMD)]
   public char[] cmds_periodic; /* periodic commands */
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = MAXRCVCMD)]
   public char[] cmd_reset; /* reset command */
   public double bl_reset;    /* baseline length to reset (km) */
   public CRITICAL_SECTION lock_flag;        /* lock flag */
};
```

Оригинальная структура на C:

```
typedef struct {        /* RTK server type */
    int state;          /* server state (0:stop,1:running) */
    int cycle;          /* processing cycle (ms) */
    int nmeacycle;      /* NMEA request cycle (ms) (0:no req) */
    int nmeareq;        /* NMEA request (0:no,1:nmeapos,2:single sol) */
    double nmeapos[3];  /* NMEA request position (ecef) (m) */
    int buffsize;       /* input buffer size (bytes) */
    int format[3];      /* input format {rov,base,corr} */
    solopt_t solopt[2]; /* output solution options {sol1,sol2} */
    int navsel;         /* ephemeris select (0:all,1:rover,2:base,3:corr) */
    int nsbs;           /* number of sbas message */
    int nsol;           /* number of solution buffer */
    rtk_t rtk;          /* RTK control/result struct */
    int nb [3];         /* bytes in input buffers {rov,base} */
    int nsb[2];         /* bytes in soulution buffers */
    int npb[3];         /* bytes in input peek buffers */
    unsigned char *buff[3]; /* input buffers {rov,base,corr} */
    unsigned char *sbuf[2]; /* output buffers {sol1,sol2} */
    unsigned char *pbuf[3]; /* peek buffers {rov,base,corr} */
    sol_t solbuf[MAXSOLBUF]; /* solution buffer */
    unsigned int nmsg[3][10]; /* input message counts */
    raw_t  raw [3];     /* receiver raw control {rov,base,corr} */
    rtcm_t rtcm[3];     /* RTCM control {rov,base,corr} */
    gtime_t ftime[3];   /* download time {rov,base,corr} */
    char files[3][MAXSTRPATH]; /* download paths {rov,base,corr} */
    obs_t obs[3][MAXOBSBUF]; /* observation data {rov,base,corr} */
    nav_t nav;          /* navigation data */
    sbsmsg_t sbsmsg[MAXSBSMSG]; /* SBAS message buffer */
    stream_t stream[8]; /* streams {rov,base,corr,sol1,sol2,logr,logb,logc} */
    stream_t *moni;     /* monitor stream */
    unsigned int tick;  /* start tick */
    thread_t thread;    /* server thread */
    int cputime;        /* CPU time (ms) for a processing cycle */
    int prcout;         /* missing observation data count */
    int nave;           /* number of averaging base pos */
    double rb_ave[3];   /* averaging base pos */
    char cmds_periodic[3][MAXRCVCMD]; /* periodic commands */
    char cmd_reset[MAXRCVCMD]; /* reset command */
    double bl_reset;    /* baseline length to reset (km) */
    lock_t lock;        /* lock flag */
} rtksvr_t;
```

В C# пытаюсь инициализировать данную структуру:

```
DataRTK.rtksvr_t rtksvr;
int iSizeRTKSRV; 
IntPtr rtksrv_ptr;

try
{
    iSizeRTKSRV = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(DataRTK.rtksvr_t));
}
catch(ArgumentException ex)
{
    string strerr = ex.Message;
}
catch(TypeLoadException ex)
{
    string strerr = ex.Message;
}

try
{
    rtksrv_ptr = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(iSizeRTKSRV);
}
catch(ArgumentException ex)
{
    string strerr = ex.Message;
}

DataRTK.rtksvr_t rtksrv = (DataRTK.rtksvr_t)(Marshal.PtrToStructure(rtksrv_ptr, typeof(DataRTK.rtksvr_t)));
```

При попытке узнать размер выдает ошибку System.ArgumentException со следующим сообщением:

> Type 'RealTimeMonitor.DataRTK+rtksvr_t' cannot be marshaled as an
>   unmanaged structure; no meaningful size or offset can be computed.

Из полезного может быть стек:

```
at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOfHelper(Type t, Boolean throwIfNotMarshalable)
at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(Type t)
at RealTimeMonitor.StreamHub.<WriteItems>d__139.MoveNext() in C:\Users\zharkov.v\source\repos\RealTimeMonitor\RealTimeMonitor\StreamHub.cs:line 138
```

Понимаю, что не может создать объект, но все же не могу понять в чем дело или я может пошел не тем путем. Без выделения памяти тоже выдает ошибку, что недостаточно памяти, поэтому переписал на этот вариант.

Кто может подсказать, что я делаю неправильно?

**ОБНОВЛЕНО 12.02.2020**

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
#pragma warning disable IDE1006 // Naming Styles
        public struct rtk_t
#pragma warning restore IDE1006 // Naming Styles
        {
                   /* RTK control/result type */
            public sol_t sol;           /* RTK solution */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 6)]
            public double[] rb;         /* base position/velocity (ecef) (m|m/s) */
            public int nx, na;          /* number of float states/fixed states */
            public double tt;           /* time difference between current and previous (s) */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = MAXSAT)]
            public double[] x, P;       /* float states and their covariance */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = MAXSAT)]
            public double[] xa, Pa;     /* fixed states and their covariance */
            public int nfix;            /* number of continuous fixes of ambiguity */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = MAXSAT)]
            public ambc_t[] ambc;       /* ambibuity control */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = MAXSAT)]
            public ssat_t[] ssat;       /* satellite status */
            public int neb;             /* bytes in error message buffer */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = MAXERRMSG)]
            public char[] errbuf;       /* error message buffer */
            public prcopt_t opt;         /* processing options */
        };




    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
#pragma warning disable IDE1006 // Naming Styles
        public struct solopt_t
#pragma warning restore IDE1006 // Naming Styles
        {
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 18)]        /* solution options type */
            public int posf;           /* solution format (SOLF_???) */
            public int times;          /* time system (TIMES_???) */
            public int timef;          /* time format (0:sssss.s,1:yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss.s) */
            public int timeu;          /* time digits under decimal point */
            public int degf;           /* latitude/longitude format (0:ddd.ddd,1:ddd mm ss) */
            public int outhead;        /* output header (0:no,1:yes) */
            public int outopt;         /* output processing options (0:no,1:yes) */
            public int outvel;         /* output velocity options (0:no,1:yes) */
            public int datum;          /* datum (0:WGS84,1:Tokyo) */
            public int height;         /* height (0:ellipsoidal,1:geodetic) */
            public int geoid;          /* geoid model (0:EGM96,1:JGD2000) */
            public int solstatic;      /* solution of static mode (0:all,1:single) */
            public int sstat;          /* solution statistics level (0:off,1:states,2:residuals) */
            public int trace;          /* debug trace level (0:off,1-5:debug) */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 2)]
            public double[] nmeaintv; /* nmea output interval (s) (<0:no,0:all) */
            /* nmeaintv[0]:gprmc,gpgga,nmeaintv[1]:gpgsv */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 64)]
            public char[] sep;       /* field separator */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 64)]
            public char[] prog;      /* program name */
            public double maxsolstd;   /* max std-dev for solution output (m) (0:all) */


        };


        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
#pragma warning disable IDE1006 // Naming Styles
        public struct sol_t
#pragma warning restore IDE1006 // Naming Styles
        {
            /* solution type */

            public gtime_t time;       /* time (GPST) */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 6)]
            public double[] rr;       /* position/velocity (m|m/s) */
            /* {x,y,z,vx,vy,vz} or {e,n,u,ve,vn,vu} */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 6)]
            public float[] qr;       /* position variance/covariance (m^2) */
            /* {c_xx,c_yy,c_zz,c_xy,c_yz,c_zx} or */
            /* {c_ee,c_nn,c_uu,c_en,c_nu,c_ue} */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 6)]
            public float[] qv;       /* velocity variance/covariance (m^2/s^2) */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 6)]
            public double[] dtr;      /* receiver clock bias to time systems (s) */
            public byte type; /* type (0:xyz-ecef,1:enu-baseline) */
            public byte stat; /* solution status (SOLQ_???) */
            public byte ns;   /* number of valid satellites */
            public float age;          /* age of differential (s) */
            public float ratio;        /* AR ratio factor for valiation */
            public float thres;        /* AR ratio threshold for valiation */
        };



[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
#pragma warning disable IDE1006 // Naming Styles
        public  struct raw_t
#pragma warning restore IDE1006 // Naming Styles
        {
                   /* receiver raw data control type */
            public gtime_t time;       /* message time */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = MAXSAT * (NFREQ + NEXOBS))]
            public gtime_t tobs;//[MAXSAT*(NFREQ+NEXOBS)]; /* observation data time */
            public obs_t obs;          /* observation data */
            public obs_t obuf;         /* observation data buffer */
            public nav_t nav;          /* satellite ephemerides */
            public sta_t sta;          /* station parameters */
            public int ephsat;         /* sat number of update ephemeris (0:no satellite) */
            public sbsmsg_t sbsmsg;    /* SBAS message */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 256)]
            public char[] msgtype;  /* last message type */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = MAXSAT * 380)]
            public char[] subfrm;  /* subframe buffer */
            public lexmsg_t lexmsg;    /* LEX message */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = MAXSAT * (NFREQ + NEXOBS))]
            public double[] lockt; /* lock time (s) */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = MAXSAT)]
            public double[] icpp;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = MAXSAT)]
            public double[] off;
            public double icpc; /* carrier params for ss2 */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = MAXSAT)]
            public double[] prCA;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = MAXSAT)]
            public double[] dpCA; /* L1/CA pseudrange/doppler for javad */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = MAXSAT * (NFREQ + NEXOBS))]
            public byte[] halfc; /* half-cycle add flag */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = MAXOBS)]
            public char[] freqn; /* frequency number for javad */
            public int nbyte;          /* number of bytes in message buffer */
            public int len;            /* message length (bytes) */
            public int iod;            /* issue of data */
            public int tod;            /* time of day (ms) */
            public int tbase;          /* time base (0:gpst,1:utc(usno),2:glonass,3:utc(su) */
            public int flag;           /* general purpose flag */
            public int outtype;        /* output message type */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = MAXRAWLEN)]
            public byte[] buff; /* message buffer */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = MAXOBS)]
            public char[] opt;      /* receiver dependent options */
            public half_cyc_t half_cyc; /* half-cycle correction list */

            public int format;         /* receiver stream format */
            public IntPtr rcv_data;     /* receiver dependent data */
        };



 [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
#pragma warning disable IDE1006 // Naming Styles
        public struct rtcm_t
#pragma warning restore IDE1006 // Naming Styles
        {
            /* RTCM control struct type */
            public int staid;          /* station id */
            public int stah;           /* station health */
            public int seqno;          /* sequence number for rtcm 2 or iods msm */
            public int outtype;        /* output message type */
            public gtime_t time;       /* message time */
            public gtime_t time_s;     /* message start time */
            public obs_t obs;          /* observation data (uncorrected) */
            public nav_t nav;          /* satellite ephemerides */
            public sta_t sta;          /* station parameters */
            public dgps_t dgps;       /* output of dgps corrections */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = MAXSAT)]
            public ssr_t[] ssr;  /* output of ssr corrections */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 128)]
            public char[] msg;      /* special message */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 256)]
            public char[] msgtype;  /* last message type */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 6 * 128)]
            public char[] msmtype; /* msm signal types */
            public int obsflag;        /* obs data complete flag (1:ok,0:not complete) */
            public int ephsat;         /* update satellite of ephemeris */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = MAXSAT * (NFREQ + NEXOBS))]
            public double[] cp; /* carrier-phase measurement */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = MAXSAT * (NFREQ + NEXOBS))]
            public short[] time_lock; /* lock time */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = MAXSAT * (NFREQ + NEXOBS))]
            public short[] loss; /* loss of lock count */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = MAXSAT * (NFREQ + NEXOBS))]
            public gtime_t[] lltime; /* last lock time */
            public int nbyte;          /* number of bytes in message buffer */
            public int nbit;           /* number of bits in word buffer */
            public int len;            /* message length (bytes) */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 1200)]
            public byte[] buff; /* message buffer */
            public uint word;  /* word buffer for rtcm 2 */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 100)]
            public uint[] nmsg2; /* message count of RTCM 2 (1-99:1-99,0:other) */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 400)]
            public uint[] nmsg3; /* message count of RTCM 3 (1-299:1001-1299,300-399:2000-2099,0:ohter) */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 256)]
            public char[] opt;      /* RTCM dependent options */
        };





#region Структуры
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]   /* time struct */
#pragma warning disable IDE1006 // Naming Styles
        public struct gtime_t
#pragma warning restore IDE1006 // Naming Styles
        {

            public IntPtr time;    /*(s) expressed by standard time_t */
            public double sec;     /*of second under 1 s */
        }

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]    /* observation data */
#pragma warning disable IDE1006 // Naming Styles
        public struct obs_t
#pragma warning restore IDE1006 // Naming Styles
        {

            public int n, nmax;      /*of obervation data/allocated */
            public obsd_t data;      /*data records */

        }




    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
#pragma warning disable IDE1006 // Naming Styles
        public struct nav_t
#pragma warning restore IDE1006 // Naming Styles
        {
            /* navigation data type */
            public int n, nmax;         /* number of broadcast ephemeris */
            public int ng, ngmax;       /* number of glonass ephemeris */
            public int ns, nsmax;       /* number of sbas ephemeris */
            public int ne, nemax;       /* number of precise ephemeris */
            public int nc, ncmax;       /* number of precise clock */
            public int na, namax;       /* number of almanac data */
            public int nt, ntmax;       /* number of tec grid data */
            public int nf, nfmax;       /* number of satellite fcb data */
            public eph_t eph;         /* GPS/QZS/GAL ephemeris */
            public geph_t geph;       /* GLONASS ephemeris */
            public seph_t seph;       /* SBAS ephemeris */
            public peph_t peph;       /* precise ephemeris */
            public pclk_t pclk;       /* precise clock */
            public alm_t alm;         /* almanac data */
            public tec_t tec;         /* tec grid data */
            public fcbd_t fcb;        /* satellite fcb data */
            public erp_t erp;         /* earth rotation parameters */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
            public double[] utc_gps;  /* GPS delta-UTC parameters {A0,A1,T,W} */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
            public double[] utc_glo;  /* GLONASS UTC GPS time parameters */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)] 
            public double[] utc_gal;  /* Galileo UTC GPS time parameters */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
            public double[] utc_qzs;  /* QZS UTC GPS time parameters */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
            public double[] utc_cmp;  /* BeiDou UTC parameters */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
            public double[] utc_irn;  /* IRNSS UTC parameters */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
            public double[] utc_sbs;  /* SBAS UTC parameters */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 8)]
            public double[] ion_gps;  /* GPS iono model parameters {a0,a1,a2,a3,b0,b1,b2,b3} */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
            public double[] ion_gal;  /* Galileo iono model parameters {ai0,ai1,ai2,0} */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
            public double[] ion_qzs;  /* QZSS iono model parameters {a0,a1,a2,a3,b0,b1,b2,b3} */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 8)]
            public double[] ion_cmp;  /* BeiDou iono model parameters {a0,a1,a2,a3,b0,b1,b2,b3} */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 8)]
            public double[] ion_irn;  /* IRNSS iono model parameters {a0,a1,a2,a3,b0,b1,b2,b3} */
            public int leaps;          /* leap seconds (s) */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = MAXSAT * NFREQ)]
            public double[] lam; /* carrier wave lengths (m) */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = MAXSAT * 3)]
            public double[] cbias; /* satellite dcb (0:p1-p2,1:p1-c1,2:p2-c2) (m) */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = MAXRCV * 2 * 3)]
            public double[] rbias; /* receiver dcb (0:p1-p2,1:p1-c1,2:p2-c2) (m) */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = MAXSAT)]
            public double[] wlbias;   /* wide-lane bias (cycle) */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
            public double[] glo_cpbias;    /* glonass code-phase bias {1C,1P,2C,2P} (m) */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = MAXPRNGLO + 1)]
            public char[] glo_fcn; /* glonass frequency channel number + 8 */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = MAXSAT)]
            public pcv_t[] pcvs; /* satellite antenna pcv */
            public sbssat_t sbssat;    /* SBAS satellite corrections */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = MAXBAND + 1)]
            public sbsion_t sbsion; /* SBAS ionosphere corrections */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = MAXSAT)]
            public dgps_t dgps; /* DGPS corrections */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = MAXSAT)]
            public ssr_t ssr;  /* SSR corrections */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = MAXSAT)]
            public lexeph_t lexeph; /* LEX ephemeris */
            public lexion_t lexion;    /* LEX ionosphere correction */
            public pppcorr_t pppcorr;  /* ppp corrections */
        };


[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
#pragma warning disable IDE1006 // Naming Styles
        public struct sbsmsg_t
#pragma warning restore IDE1006 // Naming Styles
        {

            /* SBAS message type */
            public int week, tow;       /* receiption time */
            public int prn;            /* SBAS satellite PRN number */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 29)]
            public byte[] msg; /* SBAS message (226bit) padded by 0 */
        };

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct CRITICAL_SECTION
        {
            public IntPtr DebugInfo;
            public int LockCount;
            public int RecursionCount;
            public IntPtr OwningThread;
            public IntPtr LockSemaphore;
            public UIntPtr SpinCount;
        }
```

Вроде все выложил. Если что-то забыл допишите.

**ОБНОВЛЕНО 12.02.2020 13:28**

Проблемы многие исправил, но осталась, которую не могу решить

Реализация на C

```
typedef struct half_cyc_tag {  /* half-cycle correction list type */
    unsigned char sat;  /* satellite number */
    unsigned char freq; /* frequency number (0:L1,1:L2,2:L5) */
    unsigned char valid; /* half-cycle valid flag */
    char corr;          /* half-cycle corrected (x 0.5 cyc) */
    gtime_t ts,te;      /* time start, time end */
    struct half_cyc_tag *next; /* pointer to next correction */
}half_cyc_t;
```

Реализовал на C# так

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
#pragma warning disable IDE1006 // Naming Styles
        public struct half_cyc_t
#pragma warning restore IDE1006 // Naming Styles
        {
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 7)]   /* half-cycle correction list type */
            public byte sat;  /* satellite number */
            public byte freq; /* frequency number (0:L1,1:L2,2:L5) */
            public byte valid; /* half-cycle valid flag */
            public char corr;          /* half-cycle corrected (x 0.5 cyc) */
            public gtime_t ts, te;      /* time start, time end */
            //[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = )]
            public unsafe half_cyc_t* next; /* pointer to next correction */
        };
```

Выдает вот что

> Cannot marshal field 'half_cyc' of type 'raw_t': The type definition
>   of this field has layout information but has an invalid
>   managed/unmanaged type combination or is unmarshalable.

Comment: gtime есть в описании такая структура, sat - массив структур sat_t, а вот IntPtr попробую и отвечу

Comment: Не работает с IntPtr, выходит та же самая ошибка. Может что-то ломается не в этом месте

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не засчитал предыдущий ответ, как ответ, так как слишком он общий. И сам уже подобные ошибки исправил до появления ответа. Ну а теперь по порядку.

**Ошибка №1**
В структуре `solopt_t` удаляем строку  `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 18)]` перед описанием элементов структуры.

**Ошибка №2**
В структуре `exterr_t` заменяем  `public double cerr; /* code errors (m) */` на  `public double[] cerr; /* code errors (m) */`, так как перед ней стоит `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4  NFREQ  2)]`

**Ошибка №3**
В структуре `raw_t` заменяем строку `gtime tobs` на `gtime[] tobs` - причина та же

**Ошибка №4**
В структуре `obsd_t` заменяем строку `double L` на `double[] L`... Ну вы уже поняли)))

**Ошибка №5**
В структуре `raw_t` заменяем строку `lexeph_t lexeph` на `lexeph_t[] lexeph`.

**Ошибка №6**
В структуре `raw_t` заменяем строку `sbsion_t sbsion` на `sbsion_t[] sbsion`.

**Ошибка №7**
Самая сложная, искал в другом месте, но оказалось...
Удалить строку перед началом описания элементов  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 7)]

**Ошибка №8**
Структура `rtksvr` заменить `sbsmsg_t sbsmsg` на `sbsmsg_t[] sbsmsg`.

**Ошибка №9**
Структура `rtksvr` заменить `obs_t obs` на `obs_t[] obs`.

**Ошибка №10**
Структура `rtksvr` заменить `stream_t obs` на `stream_t[] obs`.

Можно было бы засчитать и предыдущий ответ, но я эти ошибки исправил, о которых он говорит, но зато не исправил, которые в нем не указаны и по поводу соответствия типов P/Invoke - совсем не в ту сторону, так как очень много пришлось перечитать.

**PS** Спасибо огромное моим друзьям из Павлодара, Караганды и особенно Таганрога за неоценимую помощь в решении данного вопроса и не только этого.

Answer (score 2):

Как минимум, вот этот элемент выглядит ошибочным:

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 18)]        /* solution options type */
public int posf;
```

Управляемый тип int, а неуправляемый - массив?

Кроме того, у вас много других несоответствий, которые хоть и не могут привести к этой ошибке, но из-за них код не будет работать правильно. Например в неуправляемой структуре:

```
unsigned char *buff[3];
```

Это массив из трех указателей на байт

В управляемой:

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3)]
public byte[] buff;
```

Это массив из трех байтов (значений). Они не эквивалентны. Проверьте все свои структуры, что они правильно используют типы в соответствии с рекомендациями [Marshaling Data with Platform Invoke](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/marshaling-data-with-platform-invoke).

Comment: Да, и там не одна такая строчка. сейчас мучаюсь над более сложной ошибкой. С байтом все нормально можете почитать документацию от Microsot про соответствии типов в P/Invoke.